# How do I allow only specific programs to access a certain folder?

Tags: windows-10

Example: Only MyExe.exe and the Administrator is allowed to access folder "c:\MyExeFiles", no other program.

Comment: Hi, check this out https://superuser.com/questions/592216/restrict-access-to-a-folder-by-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible.

But you can run the app under another user account. See the [RunAs](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command.

Folder rights can be limited per user or user groups, so as far as I know the only was is to assign another user exclusive rights to the folder along with Administrators and deny others and use the RunAs command to run the program as that user

Comment: How ironic that you say you think it was not possible just to proceed with an explaination on how to accomplish exactly what I want :)

Comment: I meant it wasn't possible normally, what I said was a work around, anyway glad I helped xD